# access master page control from content page in c#

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, submenu

I have got menu like:

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu" runat ="server"> 
     <li id="menulink">
         <a href="#" class="menulink">Mant</a>
             <ul> 
                 <li id="mant"><a href="Mant.aspx">Table</a></li> 
            </ul> 
     </li> 
</ul>
```

On homepage load, i want to disable the mant sub-menu based on access rights.
Is there a way to achieve this on page load.

Comment: I tried using : Menu MasterPageMenu = (Menu)this.Master.FindControl("menu").FindControl("mant") as Menu; MasterPageMenu.Visible = false; But it is giving null refernce error

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this on Page_Load event handler:

```
Menu MasterPageMenu = (Menu)this.Master.FindControl("menu");

foreach (MenuItem mi in MasterPageMenu.Items[0].ChildItems)
{
    //Do your logic.
}
```

Comment: I tried using : Menu MasterPageMenu = (Menu)this.Master.FindControl("menu").FindControl("mant") as Menu;
        MasterPageMenu.Visible = false; But it is giving null refernce error

Answer (score 0):

Provide a public method `ShowMant(bool show)` in your master-page codebehind class. Cast the content-page's `Master` property to the actual type of your master and call that method. You need to make the li `runat=server` to access it on serverside in that method.

Something like (i don't know what you meanw with "disable the mant sub-menu based on access rights"):

```
public void ShowMant(bool show)
{
    if(show)
        mant.Attributes["class"] = "showMantClass";
    else
        mant.Attributes["class"] = "hideMantClass";
}
```

You use it in this way (in content-page):

```
var myMaster = this.Master as MyMasterType;
if(myMaster != null)
    myMaster.ShowMant(false);
```